# Could controlling the oceans result in a wide-spread freeze?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, climate, weather, ocean

My idea is a device that gives its user great power over the ocean, its currents, and presumably temperatures. Could this be used to dramatically (and in relatively short time) effect the climate of a region near the ocean, causing a widespread freeze?

Alternately, could a device that has power over weather patterns then be used to affect the ocean, such as changing currents or causing widespread flooding?

Comment: Of course. Both options are valid provided the devices are magical enough. The first device is known as Alexias; all the user has to say is *"Alexias, Oceanum congela!"* and the oceans will be frozen solid, from the depth of the deepest trench to the shores of the warm seas. The second device is known as Quart-Anna. At the command *"Quart-Anna, let the Ocean flood them!"* the waters of the [Ocean River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanus) will move uphill unto land, causing untold flooding, death and destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be done. This is called [climatic engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_engineering).

---

You can take as an example for your first proposal Scandinavia Peninsule. The latitude of the North of this peninsule is northern enougth to have permanent ice on his landmasses.

This is not what happens, as [Gulf Stream Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_Stream) warms the zone.

> [image: North Atlantic Ocean currents]
>
> Source: [geography.name](http://geography.name/gulf-stream/)

If you'd do geoengineering on North Atlantic Ocean, blocking the current with a big structure, Scandinavia would get freezed as the north of North America next winter.

---

For flooding, at a fantasy world, you could alter tidal cycles or you could also create tsunamis and block the reflux with a dam. Then your land zone would be flooded.